# Why is my Radix Sort JAVA implementation slower than Quick sort?

Tags: java, radix-sort

I'm trying to write radix code using ByteBuffer.allocate() 
I've learnt that radix sort's time complexity is O(kn) and I wrote this code to make k=4.
I also wrote quick sort and figured out my radix sort is 2~3 times slower than quick sort. 
Is it because of inefficient memory access? 
Here's my radix sort code.

```
private static int[] radixSort(int[] value)
{

    byte[][] valueByBytes = new byte[value.length][4];
    for (int i=0; i<value.length; i++) {
        valueByBytes[i] = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(value[i]).array();
    }

    for (int key = 3; key >=0; key--) {
        valueByBytes = countingSort(valueByBytes, key);
    }

    for (int i=0; i<value.length; i++) {
        value[i] = ByteBuffer.wrap(valueByBytes[i]).getInt();
    }
    return (value);
}

private static byte[][] countingSort(byte[][] valueByBytes, int key) {
    int[] countingArr = new int[256]; // 0 ~ 255
    byte[][] toReturnArr = new byte[valueByBytes.length][4];
    for (int i=0; i<256; i++) {
        countingArr[i] = 0;
    }

    int[] intArr = new int[valueByBytes.length];

    if (key > 0) {
        for (int j=0; j<valueByBytes.length; j++) {
            intArr[j] = (int) valueByBytes[j][key] >= 0 ? valueByBytes[j][key] : 256+valueByBytes[j][key];
        }
    }
    else {
        for (int j=0; j<valueByBytes.length; j++) {
            intArr[j] = (int) valueByBytes[j][key] + 128;
        }
    }

    for (int j=0; j<intArr.length; j++) {
        countingArr[intArr[j]]++;
    }

    for (int i=1; i<256; i++) {
        countingArr[i] = countingArr[i-1] + countingArr[i];
    }

    for (int j=intArr.length-1; j>=0; j--) {
        toReturnArr[countingArr[intArr[j]]-1] = valueByBytes[j];
        countingArr[intArr[j]]--;
    }

    return toReturnArr;
}
```

Comment: To start with, how have you determined that it's 2-3 times slower?

Comment: First, as kaya3 noted: how did you verify that? Benchmarking Java code (especially microbenchmarking) can be very tricky and it's easy to get misleading figure. Second, a better big-O doesn't always translate into better real-world performance, since constant and other lower-order factors **do** matter in the real world and are ignored in big-O. Third, radix-sort is weird and really only makes sense if your keys are big.

Comment: @kaya3 I measured time using System.nanoTime() for both code like below:  
long t = System.nanoTime();
v = xxSort(v); 
System.out.println((System.nanoTime() - t)/1000));

Comment: And what is `v`?

Comment: @kaya3 It's an integer array

Comment: An integer array of what length, with what contents?

Comment: Ah, I exprimented with the number of 1000 to 100000 length array and all the array shows that quick sort is 2~3 times faster than radix sort.
And the arrays' contents are created by random value from -99999 to 99999.

Comment: Then the answer is that 100,000 is not large enough for the lower asymptotic complexity to win out in this case.

Comment: @kaya3 - for 100,000 integers, with the code in my answer, it is close. Using nanoTime, the results vary a bit, but the best runs I saw were quicksort .0114 seconds, radix sort .0110 seconds.

Comment: @rcgldr OK? You should write it in your answer. Not sure why you tagged me.

Comment: @rcgldr In the OP's case, with the OP's implementation, it apparently is 2-3 times slower on 100,000 integers, so 100,000 is not enough for the OP's implementation of radix sort to beat the OP's implementation of quicksort, despite the asymptotic complexity. That is all I was saying, because that is the observation the OP was asking about. Also, your answer doesn't mention sorting 100,000 integers.

Comment: @rcgldr These details are of interest to people who have the same question as OP, not to me. There is no need to keep tagging me unless you do not understand something I have written and you would like me to clarify. You don't seem to be trying to correct something I have said, unless you are claiming that the OP's implementation of radix sort does not have radix sort's asymptotic complexity. I took for granted that it did, hence my comment, but if it doesn't then the answer to the question should be that OP has not actually implemented radix sort.

Comment: I deleted my prior comments, see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Radix sort takes O(x*k*n) time. Where K is number of digits.
Quick sort takes O(y*n*log n)
where x > y, extracting bits out of a longer key is may be an expensive operation.
Overheads used here may be causing trouble in your case.

You can get more answers by referring this question [When should we use Radix sort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146843/when-should-we-use-radix-sort)

Comment: Assuming you mean that x and y are constants, then this is a misuse of big O notation.

Answer (score 0):

Using ByteBuffer along with all the copy|convert operations is slowing down the radix sort. I tested sorting 16777216 integers, and on my system, (Intel 3770K, Windows 7 Pro 64 bit, Netbeans 8.2), the question's radix sort takes about 16.7 seconds, while the implementation of radix sort shown below takes about 0.55 seconds (about 30 times faster), while the implementation of quicksort shown below takes about 1.8 seconds.

```
package x;
import java.util.Random;

public class x {

    public static void RadixSort(int[] a)
    {
        int count = a.length;
        if(count < 2)
            return;
        int[] b = new int[count];           // allocate working array
        int [][] mIndex = new int[4][256];  // histograms | indexes
        int i,j,m,n,u;
        for(i = 0; i < count; i++){         // generate histograms
            u = a[i];
            mIndex[0][u&0xff]++;
            u >>= 8;
            mIndex[1][u&0xff]++;
            u >>= 8;
            mIndex[2][u&0xff]++;
            u >>= 8;
            mIndex[3][u+128]++;
        }
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){             // convert to indices
            m = 0;
            for(i = 0; i < 256; i++){
                n = mIndex[j][i];
                mIndex[j][i] = m;
                m += n;
            }       
        }
        for(i = 0; i < count; i++){         //  radix sort
            u = a[i];
            m = u&0xff;
            b[mIndex[0][m]++] = u;
        }
        for(i = 0; i < count; i++){
            u = b[i];
            m = (u>>8)&0xff;
            a[mIndex[1][m]++] = u;
        }
        for(i = 0; i < count; i++){
            u = a[i];
            m = (u>>16)&0xff;
            b[mIndex[2][m]++] = u;
        }
        for(i = 0; i < count; i++){
            u = b[i];
            m = (u>>24)+128;
            a[mIndex[3][m]++] = u;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = new int[16*1024*1024];
        Random r = new Random(0);
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            a[i] = r.nextInt();
        long bgn, end;
        bgn = System.currentTimeMillis();
        RadixSort(a);
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(int i = 1; i < a.length; i++){
            if(a[i-1] > a[i]){
                System.out.println("failed");
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("milliseconds " + (end-bgn));
    }
}
```

---

```
    @SuppressWarnings("empty-statement")
    public static void qsort(int[] a, int lo, int hi)
    {
        if(lo >= hi)
            return;
        int  p = a[lo+(hi-lo)/2];
        int  i = lo-1;
        int  j = hi+1;
        int t;
        while(true){                // partition
            while(a[++i] < p);
            while(a[--j] > p);
            if(i >= j)
                break;
            t     = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = t;
        }
        qsort(a, lo, j);
        qsort(a, j+1, hi);
    }
```